# I can't get my dotnet app running inside docker

Tags: c#, .net, docker, .net-core, ubuntu-22.04

I am developing dotnet 7 app on the Ubuntu 22.04 and I wanted to put the app inside docker container so I could ship it anywhere I want when I need it.

When I do `dotnet run` I get this as response

```
dotnet run
Building...
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer[8]
      The ASP.NET Core developer certificate is not trusted. For information about trusting the ASP.NET Core developer certificate, see https://aka.ms/aspnet/https-trust-dev-cert.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:7222
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5222
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: /home/fit/Desktop/webapp/Dental App
```

and I can access my app via `localhost:7222` as shown below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTlH0.png)

Here is the content of my dockerfile

```
# Multi stage Docker Image Build

# Build Stage
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /source
COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore "./Dental App.csproj" --disable-parallel
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish "./Dental App.csproj" -c release -o /app

# Serve Stage
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app ./

EXPOSE 5000


ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Dental\ App.dll"]
```

and after run container I can't access my app via any browser. I get this as output

```
$ docker container run --publish 5000:5000 appdental:latest
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: /app
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jM33L.png)

Same error appears on the Windows, and I can't find anyone with the same issue.

Best regards

Comment: Try http instead of https in your URL, and while it's not necessary your last stage of the Dockerfile should be based on the runtime rather than the sdk image.

Comment: Tried that but my app is redirecting everything to https. none of the ports work

Comment: If you're redirecting to https, what cert are you using, and how? If you don't intend for your application to handle SSL (such as when it's behind an SSL terminating reverse proxy), disable https redirection.

Comment: There is no SSL terminating proxy that will talk to the app. I would like the app itself to handle SSL. Cert is self signed

Comment: How are you loading the cert into the running application? Where is the cert stored? Is it baked into the container, or volumed in?

Comment: Actually it is the exception that I made inside firefox. So it allows the page to load without certificate via https. I haven't worked with certificates that much, so I am sort of new to this area

Comment: @gunr2171 So the way I create self signed certificate at first place was by running the `dotnet dev-certs https --trust`. This generates the pfx file I use to generate cert file with openssl and than move it to the `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates`

Answer (score 0):

This will probably fail since I don't know your structure, you are however missing some pieces in your dockerfile

Here's a modified version of your file to begin with. I've added a base as well as a build step.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 443    

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /source
COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore "./Dental App.csproj" --disable-parallel
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build "./Dental App.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "./Dental App.csproj" -c release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

# Serve Stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish ./

EXPOSE 5000


ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Dental\ App.dll"]
```

Comment: Thank you but the docker example doesn't work it throws errors. My docker builds successfully without any issues. Only issue is when I try to reach the app that is inside docker from my host system